# How to bind list of another list to telerik grid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I really got stuck here.
How do I bind a list of another list data to Telerik grid in MVC?

Example:

```
public class GetTripDetailsResponse
{
    public DateTime PersonalDriveDate { set; get; }
    public List<AllDrivesInfo> AllDrives { set; get; }
}

public class AllDrivesInfo
{
    public int TripId { set; get; }
    public string Time { set; get; }
    public string Where { set; get; }
    public decimal Miles { set; get; }
    public decimal Value { set; get; }
    public string Purpose { set; get; }
}
```

Now how to bind it to Telerik grid? How to bind to columns? How to display data?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to bind the list from another list.

```
 public ActionResult GetDrivesInfo()
        {

            List<AllDrivesInfo> AllDrives = null;

            var objDrive = new AllDrivesInfo { TripId = 1, Time = "Time", Where = "where", Miles = 10, Value = 20, Purpose = "my purpose" }; //Get Code here

            foreach (AllDrivesInfo d in objDrive)
            {

                AllDrives.Add(new AllDrivesInfo { TripId = d.TripId, Time = d.Time, Where = d.Where, Miles = d.Miles, Value = d.Value, Purpose = d.Purpose });
            }

        }
```

**Bind Telerik GridView**

You need to return Json result to bind the gridview:

```
 public ActionResult Drives_Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
             //Bind "DrivesList" here
            return Json(DrivesModel.DrivesList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

**Gridview**

```
.Read(read => read.Action("Drives_Get", "Drives"))
```